# Android - Merge mp3 files

Tags: android, audio, join, mp3

I'm trying to merge some mp3 file in an android application with this function:

```
private void mergeSongs(File mergedFile, Vector<InputStream> inputStreams){

    Enumeration<InputStream> enu = inputStreams.elements();

    try {

        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(enu);

        if(!mergedFile.exists()){
            mergedFile.createNewFile();}

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);

        int temp;

        while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){

            fos.write((byte)temp);

        }

        for (int i=0; i<inputStreams.size(); i++){

            InputStream fis1 = inputStreams.get(i);

            fis1.close();

        }

        sis.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

called by this few lines of code:

```
Vector<InputStream> inputStreams = new Vector<InputStream>();


    try {

        for (int i=1; i<6; i++){

            InputStream fis1 = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("a" + i, "raw", getPackageName()));

            inputStreams.add(fis1);

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mergeSongs(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mergedFile.mp3"), inputStreams);
```

This is working, but the duration of the merged audio is the same as the first audio.
How can I solve that?

*I've tried to get the duration in three different ways:
1) With mediaplayer on android
2) With MediaMetadataRetriever in android
(And all these two return the same wrong lenght)
3) With windows explorer and windows media player that return the correct lenght

Comment: You can't just concatenate files to "merge" them. mp3 files contain header information, tags, frames, etc. Google a bit.

Comment: So do i have to use some specific libraries?

Comment: You can use www.google.com to find it yourself. Asking for libraries and other off-site resources is specifically verboten.